# How to Get Window Variable Using WebdriverIO

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to run webdriverio with PhantomJS/Chrome to load a page and then grab the window object for use with other scripts. For some reason I am unable to get the window object. Everytime I get, I end up seeing output like this:

```
Title is: XXXXX
{ state: 'pending' }
```

Using the following script:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        logLevel: 'verbose'
    }
};

var client = webdriverio.remote(options);

client
     .init()
     .url('https://xxxx.com')
     .waitUntil(function () {
         return client.execute(function () {
             return Date.now() - window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd > 40000;
        }).then(function (result) {
             console.log(window);
             return window;
         });
     })
     .end();
```

Does anyone know how I can fix my code so that the window object is returned to my NodeJS console app after the page is completely loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window is an object in the browser's DOM, so it's only available inside of the 'execute' function. If you wanted access to it, you could return it from your **['execute'](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/execute.html)** function:

```
return client.execute(function () {
     return window;
}).then(function (result) {
     console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This work as well:

```
browser.execute('return window');
```